# Add days from parameter

Tags: javascript

I need to add a certain amount of days to the date object using parameters in a radio button from an onclick event handler in JavaScript. When I simply add the day to the end it just adds a 1 etc on the end of the date. Any ideas?

```
var dateObject = new Date();
var month = dateObject.getMonth();

var monthArray = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April",  
                           "May", "June", "July", "August",
                           "September","October","November","December");

function orderReadyDate(orderTime) 
{
    var dateToday = monthArray[month] + " " + dateObject.getDate() + ", " + dateObject.getFullYear();
    document.forms[0].txtPickupDate.value = dateToday;
}
```

Here are my input buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="item" value="print_5x7" onclick="orderReadyDate(1)" />5x7 Prints(1 day)<br />
<input type="radio" name="item" value="poster" onclick="orderReadyDate(1)" />Poster (1 day)<br />
<input type="radio" name="item" value="mug" onclick="orderReadyDate(2)" />Coffee Mug (2 days)<br />
<input type="radio" name="item" value="shirt" onclick="orderReadyDate(3)" />T-shirt (3 days)</p>
```

Comment: I understand you accepted his answer but an upvote would be appreciated since he essentially just improved upon my answer

Comment: @JamesDaly—but your answer will fail for any date where date + order time goes beyond the end of the month.

Comment: I do agree with James though he gave me the answer I was looking for. (I would do it but I'm not a 15, sorry..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to try this:- Notice the setDate method which will add up the date.

```
 var newdate = new Date();
 newdate.setDate(newdate.getDate() + orderTime);
 var dateToday = monthArray[newdate.getMonth()] + " " + 
                 newdate.getDate() + ", " + 
                 newdate.getFullYear();
```

Comment: You should ensure that the value of `orderTime` is a number before adding it to `dateToday`. If it's a string, you might be surprised at the resulting date. E.g. you might do: `newdate.getDate() + +orderTime`.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dateToday = monthArray[month] + " " 
        + (dateObject.getDate() + orderTime) 
        + ", " + dateObject.getFullYear();
```

Comment: so in your case it would be + orderTIme

Comment: Did you accept this answer already. Think about it. What if the day is 31st and you are adding 1 would you show 32 as date. Similarly the case of leapyear, end of the month, end of the year etc needs to be considered.